# Cannot publish web app : Fail to copy

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I was able to publish my web applications a thousand times, now I'm stuck with an error (sorry for my not perfect french translating)

> Error  23  Fail to copy file : "blabla\BLL.dll." to "blabla\BLL.dll" Cannot find file 'blabla\BLL.dll'.

What is that all about?

Edit: it's in the PackageTmp files

Comment: You should check the reference for this file. May be you must mark it as Copy Always, then try to Publish the web app again

Comment: But if my references were wrong, how comes it only fails now ?

Comment: You could have a file lock (file in use) preventing it from being copied.  Completely close Visual Studio and reboot and see if it goes away.  Try that first then we'll go from there.

Comment: I had the same idea 2 min ago, didn't work

Comment: I recently added some #If DEBUG tags in the BLL can it be related to my problem ?

Comment: there is a warning telling me that novell directory haven't been resolve, first time i see that

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my awsome colleague suggested I delete the "obj" file...
It worked, I don't know where she learned that. It solved the problem completely.